# Spring Boot: how to idiomatically configure Schema Registry Serdes in spring-kafka

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Are there examples of configuring `SpecificAvroSerdes` (or any schema registry-based serdes - JsonSchema and Protobuf) in `spring-kafka` that allow leveraging some of the autoconfiguration (based on `yaml` or `properties` files).

There are a few similar questions in SO like [How to use Spring-Kafka to read AVRO message with Confluent Schema registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979389/how-to-use-spring-kafka-to-read-avro-message-with-confluent-schema-registry)

But I want to be a bit specific on Kafka Streams serdes and declarative configuration of the Serdes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Kafka Streams can be configured with the default Serde.
See `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG` and `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG`.

According Spring Boot convention we can provide any arbitrary properties from YAML file: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props

So, probably your `SpecificAvroSerdes` can be configured in the `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.kafka.streams.properties[default.value.serde]=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerdes
```